# Conjugate operator of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Give a integral operator 
$$
L(\phi) = \int \omega \phi d\mu
$$
where $\omega$ is a given function. I want to find the conjugate operator of $L$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, i.e. find a $L^*$ such that
$$
\int \psi L(\phi) d\mu =  \int\phi L^*(\psi)~~~~~\forall \psi\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)
$$
Then ,how to find it ?

Comment: Fubini theorem maybe?

Comment: Is Your integral operator defined by $L\phi(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\omega(x,y)\phi(y)d\mu$ with an appropriate kernel $\omega:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ or how exactly is it defined?